# Why do Cocoa apps use so much memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory

Even the standard blank-window Cocoa app that gets built when you make a new Cocoa project in Xcode uses almost 6 MB of memory. What's the reason for this? Is it possible to make an app use less, or does OS X simply manage memory differently for Cocoa apps?

Not that I'm complaining. I know that performance "hardly matters anymore" (edit: what I mean is, it matters less than readability/maintainability/the programmer's time). I'm just curious.

Comment: Am the only one annoyed by the idea the performance doesn't matter anymore?

Comment: It's not that performance doesn't matter.  There's a trade-off between 100% optimal performance and using a framework that adds some overhead but makes development much easier.  So yeah, 6MB for a blank window is high, but if the framework lets you develop apps in less time, it's worth it.

Comment: How are you measuring how much "ram" an application is using? Are you looking at RPRVT in top, or something else?

Comment: @Chris Hanson: I was just looking under the Real Memory usage pane in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OS X does a lot of magic with shared memory and copy-on-write pages, so chances are that it doesn't take that much physical RAM for every application.

You can check exactly how memory blocks are mapped by running:

```
sudo vmmap <PID of the process>
```

Comment: There's also a very basic hit: all windows on osx are double buffered - so 2*window width*window height*4 bytes are going to be used just opening a window

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the all the framework (APIs) you use. Combine that with the VM allocations done by low level ops.

It's only worth trying to reduce the heap alloc (total), as well as the resident size of the code. Making sure your data structs are allocated efficiently and trying to compile with the ever-so-famous "-Os" optimization flag (size optimization). There isn't much you can do about the VM eaten by Cocoa. I wouldn't really worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a 'WTF' moment for developers in general. The question is usually - why does my trivial application use up so much memory.

The answer is down to the underlying framework. You could argue that 6MB is too much, but really, it is nothing.

It's not rare to see computers come with 2GB of memory these days. The stock IMAC is 4GB. The whole point of the computer industry is to use up all the resources a machine has so that it continues to evolve.

Yes you should avoid ineffecincies where possible (Don't load up a 5million point array at start up for instance). But unless your beta demonstrates you fudged up just keep it on the list of todo's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit out on a limb here, but I guess it's because all the libraries that get added have to do quite a bit of setting up and there is no need to garbage collect, so they simply get to waste memory; plus, even if all memory got autoreleased, it would wait until the first idle event, which is after the creation of the window. Delete unneeded libraries/frameworks, or force a garbage collect somewhere after loading the window from the nib and see how much it goes down if you're so concerned.

I am not concerned about it. Some of the memory might be returned later, and the rest is the price you pay for a powerful framework.

Answer (score 1):

A factor which is not directly linked to cocoa but is valid to frameworks in general is that the overhead is not linear. There is usually a fixed and a variable "price", in terms of overhead, to use the framework.

When you create a simple blank window, the fixed overhead is crushing, but when you create an application with tens of windows, dialogs, controls and all, the initial fixed overhead becomes negligible, against the size of the application itself.